# SVN: do not commit specific line in specific file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

Is there a way to mark specific lines in specific files to ignore for commit? For example the csproj-file of C# Projects Line 5:

```
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
```

Comment: No. SVN doesn't commit based on lines. It commits based on files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Files that contain user/machine dependent settings should not be part of Subversion. Instead have your build instantiate the correct version from a template (that is controlled by Subversion).